# On what block levels within a cycle can roll snapshots happen?

Tags: baking, snapshots, baking-rights

According to [this documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html):

> Roll snapshots represent the state of rolls for a given block. Roll
> snapshots are taken every BLOCKS_PER_ROLL_SNAPSHOT = 256 blocks, which
> is 16 times per cycle. There is a tradeoff between memory consumption
> and economic efficiency. If roll snapshots are too frequent, they will
> consume a lot of memory. If they are too rare, strategic participants
> could purchase many tokens in anticipation of a snapshot and resell
> them right after.

But this does not say on which levels the snapshots are taken. It's likely that the answer is either `0, 256, ..., 3840` or `256, 512, ..., 4096` but it's not specified which one it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is done at the levels corresponding to the cycle positions `255, 511, ..., 4095`.
Given that `cycle_position == (level - 1) % 4096` (the first cycle has started at level 1, genesis being special), the levels are `256, 512, ...`

The relevant code is [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/13067b9557fb1d00d0f4f689248a1a37c891665d/src/proto_006_PsCARTHA/lib_protocol/apply.ml#L1308):

```
let may_snapshot_roll ctxt =
  let level = Alpha_context.Level.current ctxt in
  let blocks_per_roll_snapshot = Constants.blocks_per_roll_snapshot ctxt in
  if
    Compare.Int32.equal
      (Int32.rem level.cycle_position blocks_per_roll_snapshot)
      (Int32.pred blocks_per_roll_snapshot)
  then Alpha_context.Roll.snapshot_rolls ctxt
  else return ctxt
```

So the relevant cycle_position are those `cp` such that `cp % 256 == 255`.

Comment: Don't confuse `level` and `cycle_position` ;) The code actually says `cycle_position % 256 == 255` which is equal to `(level - 1) % 256 == 255` which is equal to `level % 256 == 0`.

Comment: That's because level didn't start at 0 with the first block of a cycle right?

Comment: Oh, I had in mind "relative" levels, relative to the start of the protocol...
Indeed, `cycle_position == (level - 1) % 4096` is true for mainnet.
I'll update my answer.
@ArthurB: right.